# Is an out-of-band request via DNS by abusing the X-Forwarded-For header exploitable

Tags: http, webserver, vulnerability, dns

By changing the `X-Forwarded-For` header in a request, I am able to have it sent an OOB interaction with Burp Collaborator requesting  a `DNS lookup of type A`.

Is there any risk to this *vulnerability* or should this just be reported as an information disclosure of an internal IP?

[image: Burp DNS query]